# How to track "page views per minute" using Google Analytics Real Time API?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics Real Time API (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) to track the active visitors per minute. For this, I use the metric `rt:activeVisitors`. Everything is working fine.

However, I want to track the *page views per minute*, but I did not find any overview of available metrics.

Is it possible to fetch the current page views?

Comment: What technology are you using to read the analytics? html/JS? C#? I'm finding code samples to be scarce..

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of the Dimensions and metrics available in the RealTime API here :  [Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/)

It doesnt look like page views is something you can see in the RealTime API

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is to use *pagePath* dimension and have *activeVisitors* as the basic metric (and the only one available, pretty much).

I don't think there is any real value in having live page view stats, you can find those in real time reports built-in standard GA reporting set anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As seen here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/pagetracking

You can use

```
rt:pageviews
```

the documentation is not really clear on the time frame. But my experiments seem to hint per minute.